# How to identify outlying raters

Tags: agreement-statistics, spearman-rho, cohens-kappa, data-preprocessing

I have collected data from 500 anonymous online respondents who rated the acceptability of two variations of a large number of sentences (3-level categorical data: excellent, acceptable, impossible). I suspect that some of the respondents' data is somewhat random (or at least very sloppy), and I need an empirical way to justify excluding their data.

Some items are grammatically incorrect, so one possibility is to remove all raters who marked those items as acceptable or excellent. However, I have noticed that some raters who marked a grammatically incorrect sentence as acceptable have data that is otherwise very similar to other respondents, so that particular response appears to just be noise in the data, perhaps an inadvertent click.

The data look something like this: (1=excellent, 2=acceptable, 3=impossible)

```
ID       1a   1b   2a   2b   3a   3b   ...
==========================================
personA  1    3    2    2    3    1    ...
personB  1    3    1    2    3    1    ...
personC  1    2    1    2    1    2    ...
personD  1    3    2    2    3    1    ...
```

How can I quantify that `personC`'s data is not valid?

Comment: It's a clumsy solution, but if you have some sense of whether a response is correct or incorrect (i.e. if an ungrammatical item is rated excellent) then could you not just calculate the percentage of correct responses per person and remove anyone who performs particularly poorly?

Comment: Do you really want to exclude certain raters or perhaps rather reflect that there are some inter-person differences in rating style? Have a look at item response theory - a typical model could certainly capture whether certain people have a tendency to be always very positive or negative - or if you go a step further are very random compared to other raters. Such a model would not per-se exclude any raters, but rather someone who always rates everything as excellent or seems to randomly pick compared to other raters may then end up having less influence.

Comment: @Ian_Fin only a very small percentage of the items are objectively correct or incorrect.